# How can I assign columns from one data frame to another, when the ID is the same? Using isin() - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, match, isin

**I am using python and pandas.**

I have:

```
df1:              df2:
|index | ID |     |index | ID  | name  |
|  1   | 34 |     |  1   |  35 | Astri |
|  2   | 35 |     |  2   |  36 | Carlos|
|  3   | 36 |     |  3   |  34 | Xim   |
```

So, i want somthing like this using isin():

```
df1:
    |index | ID | name   |
    |  1   | 34 | Xim    |
    |  2   | 35 | Astri  |
    |  3   | 36 | Carlos |
```

The function I am using is this. I can tell if the ID of df1 exists in df2, but I am unable to assign the 'name' column of df2, to df1

```
df1 = df1[df1.ID.isin(df2.ID)]
```

**I don't want to have to iterate using a FOR and iterrows(), because I will apply this to a dataset of eight million records. Thank you!**

Comment: This case is hypothetical, the real columns are purchased sources with different columns. Basically what I need is the explained.

Answer (score 0):

This is merging two dataframes together. consider `merge` or `join`.

`df1 = df1.merge(df2, how = 'left', on = 'ID')`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Regarding your code, I need to condition by the ID, if I paste the df2 next to df1 the IDs will not match because in the original source they are document ID